# How to copy the file names defined in a property file using ant script

Tags: java, ant

I have a property file say test.properties.It contains the filenames as below.

- web/WEB-INF/a.java
- web/b.jsp

I want to read these file names from the properties file test.properties and copy these file names to a directory.Please help me resolve this problem.Stack over flow is the only hope now.Thanks in advance.

So far what I have thought to resolve this is load the properties file as below

```
<loadfile property="path" srcFile="${basedir}/test.properties"/>
```

But how do I resolve the property "path" contents?

Comment: Do you have fixed number of files?

Comment: No ,The number of files keeps on changing

Comment: If you don't have keys then it is not a properties file. By convention `*.properties` files have the format that is read by `java.util.Properties` and it will be best to name the file something else.

Comment: ok ,then I will name it as .txt file.But how shall I go about fixing the bove problem?

Comment: @user3313366 Martin Clayton has provided the answer. Using the "includesfile" attribute on the fileset is the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To load properties from a file you should use the [loadproperties](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html) task

**Update**

I have revised the answer adding a second example that reads from a text file instead of a properties file. It uses an embedded [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task) script to read the file and copy it to the target directory.

I warn against using [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/). It is very popular but in my experience if you need to perform complex processing you are better off using a normal programming language. Javascript is an obvious option (doesn't require additional jars), but I like groovy due to its excellent integration with ANT.

## Example1: Using properties file

```
├── build.properties
├── build.xml
└── src
    ├── a.java
    └── b.jsp
```

### build.properties

```
file1=src/a.java
file2=src/b.jsp
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="copy">

  <loadproperties srcFile="build.properties"/>

  <target name="copy">
    <copy file="${file1}" todir="target" verbose="true"/>
    <copy file="${file2}" todir="target" verbose="true"/>
  </target>

</project>
```

## Example2: Using text file

```
├── build.txt
├── build.xml
└── src
    ├── a.java
    └── b.jsp
```

### build.txt

```
src/a.java
src/b.jsp
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="copy">

  <target name="bootstrap">
    <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
    <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/groovy-all.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.2.1/groovy-all-2.2.1.jar"/>
  </target>

  <target name="copy">
    <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>
    <groovy>
    new File("build.txt").eachLine {
      ant.copy(file:it, todir:"target", verbose:true)
    }
    </groovy>
  </target>

</project>
```

**Notes:**

- Run "ant bootstrap" to install the 3rd party groovy jar from Maven Central.

Comment: Thanks mark,But the number of files defined in the properties file keeps changing.And there is no key holder like file1= or file2= in the properties file it just has contents like src/a.java

Comment: @user3313366 I have revised my answer adding an additional example that reads the files to be copied from a text file. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Mark.Nice solution with groovy

Answer (score 1):

```
<project name="sample">

  <property file="test.properties"/>

  <target name="copy">
    <copy file="${src1}" todir="dest" />
    <copy file="${src2}" todir="dest" />
  </target>

</project>
```

Here src1 and src2 are the paths variables defined in your test.properties.

EDIT:

In that case you can use load file in combination with for task (to read file line by line) like this:

```
<project name="sample">

  <taskdef resource="net/sf/antcontrib/antcontrib.properties">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="path/to/ant-contrib.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </taskdef>

<loadfile property="file" srcfile="test.txt"/>

  <target name="copy">
    <for param="line" list="${file}" delimiter="${line.separator}">
      <sequential>
        <copy file="@{line}" todir="dest" />
      </sequential>
    </for>
  </target>
 </project>
```

you have to use `ant-contrib` for `for` task.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks sanjeev.But this will not work for me becasue I dont have any keyholder thing in the properties file.Properties file just has the complte filename with like web/WEB-INF/a.java .... and so on ,on each  line and also the number of files defined in the properties keeps changing

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use a [`<fileset>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html) or [`<files>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/resources.html#files) resource collection with a [`<copy>` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html).

```
<copy todir="${dest.dir}">
    <fileset dir="${src.dir}" includesfile="${list_of_files.file}" />
</copy>
```

A `fileset` uses paths relative to the directory specified in the `dir` attribute.
If the paths in your list-of-files file are absolute paths, then you should use `files` rather than `fileset`.

If you want to copy all the files to a single directory:

```
src/a.txt   --> dest/a.txt
src/b/b.txt --> dest/b.txt
```

rather than

```
src/a.txt   --> dest/a.txt
src/b/b.txt --> dest/b/b.txt
```

then use a `<copy>` task with a flatten:

```
<copy todir="${dest.dir}" flatten="yes">
    ...
</copy>
```

You can apply more complex name mapping rules using the `<copy>` task [`<mapper>` element](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html).

Comment: +1 I have never used the "includesfile" attribute on the filesset. Missed it in the documentation.